# How do I change the default file manager for opening downloads in Skype?

Tags: skype, default-programs

In Skype on Ubuntu, you can click a little folder icon next to  a download to open the directory containing the download:

[image: Screenshot]

When I click the folder icon, the folder is always opened in Nautilus? How do I change the file manager used to open this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skype uses a program called `mimeopen` to open the folder.

To choose a new default file manager to open directories, run this in a terminal:

```
mimeopen --ask-default ~/Downloads/
```

You should get output similar to the following:

```
Please choose a default application for files of type inode/directory

    1) Files  (nautilus)
    2) Disk Usage Analyzer  (baobab)
    3) Files  (nautilus-folder-handler)
    4) Open Folder with Thunar  (Thunar-folder-handler)
    5) Other...
```

Simply choose the correct number, and Skype should use your default choice from now on.